# Retrieving data from JSON object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have response JSON object which has a `series` array of objects like this:

```
{
series: [
    {
    name: 'a',
    data: [1,2,3]
    },
    {
    name: 'b',
    data: [4,5,6]
    }
]
}
```

What I want is to retrieve the `data` values corresponding to the `name` value.

So far I have come to this:

```
$scope.nameArr[i] = response.series[i].name;
```

which is giving me correct `name` array but for the corresponding data value my below code is failing

```
for(var i=0; i<response.series.length; i++) {
    $scope.nameArr[i] = response.series[i].name;
       for (var j=0; j<response.series[i].data.length; j++){                                
             $scope.dataArr[j] = response.series[i].data[j];
       }
}
```

Comment: try this

      
     angular.forEach(series,function(item){
          $scope.nameArr.push(item.name);
       })

Comment: what is your expected outcome?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
angular.forEach(series,function(item,index){
    $scope.nameArr.push(item.name);
    $scope.dataArr.push(item.data);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `array.filter` to get the data by name.
The for loop would also work and you don't need the nested loop for this.

I would prefer the filter because it's easier to read but the for-loop is probably a bit faster in execution time.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/bzL5tkjo/).

```js
var response = {
  series: [{
    name: 'a',
    data: [1, 2, 3]
  }, {
    name: 'b',
    data: [4, 5, 6]
  }]
};

function getDataByName(name) {
  return response.series.filter(function(item, index) {
    console.log(item);
    return (item.name == name);
  });
}

var filtered = getDataByName('a');
console.log(filtered[0].data);
$('#result').append('with filter: ' + JSON.stringify(filtered[0].data) + '<br/>');

var item, series = [];
var queryByName = 'a';

for (var i = 0; i < response.series.length; i++) {
  item = response.series[i];
  if (item.name == queryByName) {
    series.push(item);
  }
}

$('#result').append('with for loop: ' + JSON.stringify(series[0].data));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Javascript solution, just change the way you do the foreach loop to

```
angular.forEach(array, function(item)....etc
```

Here:

```
    var x = {
series: [
    {
    name: 'a',
    data: [1,2,3]
    },
    {
    name: 'b',
    data: [4,5,6]
    }
]
}

var results = [];
x.series.forEach(function(item) {
    item.data.forEach(function(subitem) {
    results.push(subitem);
  })
});

console.log(results)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6worooos/1/

Comment: This is not what he wants. how can he retrieve the data array by name this way? -> Downvote

Comment: Then its not clear what he wants. Question should be updated with an example of the desired json result.